# How to count the quantity of rows in CSV where in column find the today's date?

Tags: php, csv, statistics

I have a file CSV: https://metalval.ru/account/data/stat/all.csv.
Needs to print the sum (count) of rows where is current date ($today) and count of rows where current week to show in stat's dashboard the quantity of orders today and on this week.

Some example is a test code in work:

```
<?php
if (($handle = fopen("https://metalval.ru/account/data/stat/all.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
$today = date("d.m.Y");
$row = 0;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
 if ($data[2] == $today) {
   $row++;
 }
 else {
   $row = 0;
 }
}
fclose($handle);
echo $row;
}
?>
```

Comment: what sorcery is that CSV file?

Comment: Remove the `$row = 0` and your count should be correct. You're resetting the count every time you encounter a date that doesn't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to remove the else condition, because every time that `$data[2]` was different than `$today` the counter was reseted.

```
if (($handle = fopen("https://metalval.ru/account/data/stat/all.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $today = date("d.m.Y");
    $row = 0;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if ($data[2] == $today) {
            $row++;
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to count quantity of orders by checking date on this week using Monday and Next Monday as period means this week, but if-condition not works correctly:

```
    <?php
if (($handle = fopen("https://metalval.ru/account/data/stat/all.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $monday = date("d.m.Y", strtotime('last Monday'));
    $nextMonday = date("d.m.Y", strtotime('next Monday'));
    $today = date("d.m.Y");
    $row = 0;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if (($monday = $data[2]) or ($monday < $data[2]) or ($today == $data[2]) or ($today < $nextMonday)) {
            $row++;
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo '<li class="ok">За неделю всего ';
    echo $row;
    echo ' заявок.</li>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).